# Laravel app not working after deploying on Heroku

Tags: heroku, laravel-8

I have a Laravel app working perfectly on my localhost, but when I deploy it on Heroku cloud, it gives the following error,

> ErrorException:
> file_put_contents(/tmp/build_a3cd0b04/storage/framework/sessions/YZFia5zZhnq2Lz2jZmdD9uZKjiQUU9KnMmRU0oad):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have tried changing permissions of the storage folder, clearing cache, etc., but nothing works. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using [the file driver](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#configuration). That isn't a very good choice on Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). It won't scale horizontally and sessions will be lost unpredictably (whenever your dyno restarts, which happens at least once per day).

I suggest using the Redis, Memcached, or database driver.

If you already have aa database, that driver is likely easiest. [You can use the `session:table` Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#database) to generate a database migration for holding session data. Commit that migration, update your `config/session.php` accordingly, redeploy, and run your migrations.

I suspect the cookie driver would also work. Basically, you can use anything but the file driver (or the toy array driver).